# Rails 4 before_action sometime doesn't work well

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

My Env

- ruby 2.1.4 (It occur in 2.1.2)
- Rails 4.1.6 (It occur in 4.1.1) development Env

I set @current_store in before_action.

```
class Store::ApplicationController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_current_store

  private
  def set_current_store
    Rails.logger.debug "set_current_store is called"
    @current_store = Store.find session[:id]
  end
end

class Store::FooController < Store::ApplicationController
  def index
    @foos = Foo.where(store_id: @current_store.id)
  end
end
```

then I access to http://my.domain/store/foos

Sometimes works well and get 200 response and I can find "set_current_store is called" in development.log, but Sometime I get 500 and I can't find "set_current_store is called" in development.log.

then I reloaded and get same error. However I open store/application_controller.rb in vim and just save (:w) without changing the code. and reload I can always get 200 response.

Why is before_action sometimes ignored?

My config/environments/development.rb

```
Rails.application.configure do
  config.cache_classes = false
  config.eager_load = false
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log
  config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load
  config.assets.debug = true
  config.assets.raise_runtime_errors = true
  config.cache_store = :redis_store, "redis://localhost:6379/0/cache", { expires_in: 90.minutes }
end
```

Comment: Don't make the method private if you want to call it from another class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Store::ApplicationController < ApplicationController
  helper_method :set_current_store

  private
  def set_current_store
    Rails.logger.debug "set_current_store is called"
    @current_store = Store.find session[:id]
  end
end

class Store::FooController < Store::ApplicationController
  before_action :set_current_store
  def index
    @foos = Foo.where(store_id: @current_store.id)
  end
end
```

Comment: @HisatakeIshibashi, i am no rails super star, i just wanted to you with the right way to code. accept the answer if it does solve problem..